# FileNotFoundException while uploading a image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

My objective is User can choose an image from any place from their desktop and upload/tweet the same to twitter. I'm struggling to set the relative path to the imagePath variable.

The path (D Drive) were my image stored. While running the application it looks in different path. This throws an error System.IO.FileNotFoundException. I tried Server.MapPath too. Assist me to resolve it.

Solved the issue as following

string filePath; string imagePath = "";

```
        if (imgFile == null)
        {
            imgFile = Request.Files["imgFile"];
        }

        if (imgFile.FileName != "")
        {
            filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }
            filePath = filePath + Path.GetFileName(imgFile.FileName);
            imgFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/"), filePath);
        }
```

Comment: First You need to upload file to your project directory then you will be able to read `stream`.

Comment: The path displayed in the imagePath variable is that of the server and not the user, first the file is saved in the server location and then start reading file.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab ..Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @LPGTE.SOFTS Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain why rated my question -1. It was just a question. Isn't it?

Comment: @Krish I didn't downvote, but I would suggest not to include images of code.... maybe that's why someone downvoted.

Comment: @10Rep Thanks for the hint.. usually I don't do that. I just did to show the value of imagePath variable on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

File must be saved in the server location, try to replace the below instruction:

```
string imagePath=Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/"),fileName);
```

with the below instruction

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
var imagePath = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(imagePath); 
........
```

Cordially